# Can't find HP Protect Tools to activate fingerprint reader on an HP ProBook 4540s

Tags: fingerprint

I got an HP ProBook 4540s in December 2012.

When I first got it, every time I booted up, there was a rather large icon, almost like a Windows 7 gadget, to access HP Protect Tools, but I had too much going on to mess with it right away and kept clicking on something like "remind me next time I log on" and determined to get acquainted with it after the holidays.

But at some point in time, that icon went away and now I can't locate it at all.

I'd like to try, and probably use, the fingerprint reader and explore whatever else is among the Protect Tools, but now I can't find them or any folder or .exe to access them.

Can anyone help me find them?

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the [HP website/support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/hp-probook-4540s-notebook-pc/5229455) and pick your operating system. Look at the *Driver - Keyboard, Mouse and Input Devices* area.

There the fingerprint recognition driver is available.

Further down the page is *Software-Security* with protectTools download options.